# Index Array in qml

Tags: qt, csv, qml

I building a GUI in Qt Creator and I want to read a CSV.
So far I can read the CSV as a HTTP Request and I can display it as a text with the following function:

```
//read CSV Datei
function readTextFile(filename){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.open("GET", filename); // set Method and File
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){ // if request_status == DONE
            var response = xhr.responseText;
            screen.liste = response
            console.log(response);
        }
    }
    xhr.send(); // begin the request
}
```

In the following I am trying to find the individual entries of the "array".
Is there a way to split this list in individual strings?
The List has 50 rows and 18 columns and the entries in one row are separated by ';'

For example here are the first two rows:

```
P22;P64;P99;P20;P88;P18;50;90;80;90;40;0;10;0;40;80;60;20
P51;P44;P57;P46;P96;P10;20;40;50;80;20;60;50;80;0;30;10;50
...
```

Comment: Don't put your logic in QML. Use C++ and interface with it to get the information you need.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SO!
The String QML type extends the JS String object (see at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-string.html#details), so you can just use the [split()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/es6/es6_string_split.htm) method to get the needed tokens in an array, which can be indexed with [].